# React-Native - Cannot scroll to bottom to view more cells in ListView

Tags: react-native

I have a ListView inside a View, this view also has a searchbar at the top of the ListView. I cannot seem to scroll to the bottom of the ListView. Could someone please show me how this would work with my code?.

### CODE

```
class Social extends Component {
                constructor(props) {
                    super(props);

                    var tabLabel = this.props.tabLabel;

                    var dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2});
                    this.state = {
                        text: 'Search ' + tabLabel + ' here...' ,
                        textInput: '',
                        dataSource:dataSource,
                    };
                  }

                    loadMoreContentAsync = async () => {
                        this.doneClick();
                      }


                  renderRow(rowData: object, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {
                      return (
                        <TouchableHighlight
                          underlayColor = '#ddd'>
                          <View style ={styles.row}>
                            <View style={styles.imagecon}>
                              <Image style={{width: 100, height: 80}} source={{uri: rowData.thumbnail}}  />
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.textcon}>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 11, fontWeight: 'bold' }} > {rowData.title}  </Text>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 11}} > {rowData.desc}  </Text>
                            </View>
                          </View>
                        </TouchableHighlight>

                      )
                    }
                        doneClick = () => {
                            this.props.showTrans();
                            fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=tupac&key=AIzaSyDFOz50C_XkuEh2T-2XTN9fqm_5xHYzbg8")
                              .then((response) => response.json())
                              .then((responseData) => {
                                console.log('fxbxfbxf' + responseData.toString());
                                console.log('ghghgh' + responseData["items"].length);
                                var arrVideos = new Array;
                                //let doc = new DomParser().parseFromString(html,'text/html')
                                for(var i = 0; i < responseData["items"].length; i++) {
                                    var title = responseData["items"][i]["snippet"].title;
                                    var thumbnail = responseData["items"][i]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["default"]["url"];
                                    var desc = responseData["items"][i]["snippet"]["description"];

                                    var video = {
                                        title : title,
                                        thumbnail: thumbnail,
                                        desc: desc
                                    }

                                    arrVideos.push(video);
                                }

                                this.setState({
                                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(arrVideos)
                                });
                                this.props.hideTrans();
                              })
                              .done();
                        }
                          render() {

                            return (
                                <View style={styles.menu} >


                                        <View style={styles.searchbar} >
                                        <Image style={{marginTop: 10 ,marginLeft: 10 , width: 20, height: 20}} source={require('./images/search.png')} />
                                        <TextInput
                                                onSubmitEditing={ this.doneClick }
                                             style={{marginLeft: 5, color: '#757575', width: width - 80, height: 40, fontSize: 11,}}
                                             onChangeText={(textInput) => this.setState({textInput})}
                                             placeholder={this.state.text}
                                              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                             />
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.sep} >
                                    </View>

                                      <ListView
                                      renderScrollComponent={props => <InfiniteScrollView {...props} />}
                                        style = {{flexDirection: 'column',
                                                      }}
                                        dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
                                        renderRow = {this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                                        renderFooter={() => <Footer />}
                                        onLoadMoreAsync={this.loadMoreContentAsync}
                                        >
                                      </ListView>
                                </View>

                            );
                          }
                        }


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
                   menu: {
                   flex:1,flexDirection: 'column',
                           },
                           searchbar: {
                               alignItems: 'flex-start',
                                flexDirection: 'row',
                            },
                           sep: {
                               alignItems: 'flex-start',
                               height: 1,
                               width: width,
                               backgroundColor: '#9E9E9E',
                            },
                           row: {
                               padding: 10,
                                  flex: 1,
                                  width: width,
                                  height:120,
                                  borderBottomWidth: 1,
                                  borderBottomColor: '#9E9E9E',
                                  flexDirection: 'row',
                           },
                           imagecon: {
                           backgroundColor: 'black',
                                padding: 5,
                             alignItems: 'center',
                          },
                           textcon: {
                              paddingLeft: 8,
                              flex: 1,
                                alignItems: 'flex-start',
                             },
                           textstyle: {
                                  fontSize: 11,
                            },
                              container: {
                                flex: 1,
                                padding: 8,
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                              },
                              button: {
                                borderColor: '#8E8E8E',
                                borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
                                paddingHorizontal: 20,
                                paddingVertical: 10,
                                borderRadius: 5,
                              },
                              text: {
                                color: '#8E8E8E',
                              },
                           });
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can try, if you haven't already resolved this, are--

A container with flex 1:

```
var {width, height} = require('Dimensions').get('window');
<View style = {styles.container} >...
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        backgroundColor: '#000099',
    },
    ...
```

and the ListView immediately inside the above View with style as

```
     <ListView  showsVerticalScrollIndicator ={false}//<=however you like
            initialListSize ={100}//sometimes this has helped me when wrapping items in a listview
            contentContainerStyle={styles.listview}//use this to reference your stylesheet
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            .../>
```

Then it can help to see the last items if in your listview style you put:

```
    listview: {
        paddingBottom: 50
    },
```

with no flex assigned in the listview. Also, the default flex orientation in React Native is column, so you don't really need to designate this. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot
initialListSize={100} will have in case wrapping items in a listview
But could you please explain why this happen?

Comment: The RN docs say about initialListSize 'Use this to make it so that the first screen worth of data appears at one time instead of over the course of multiple frames.' I don't usually use it, but sometimes I've had ListViews truncate my data, and specifying a number greater than (or equal to) the number of items I have makes it display them all.